# Overwrite input.html in Magento UI in my module

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento2.2.3

I'm trying to overwrite `input.html` in `module-ui > view > frontend > web > templates > form> element` in my module.

Somehow it isn't working whatever I try.

I currently got this in my `requirejs-config.js`.

```
var config = {
config: {
    mixins: {
        'Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping': {
            'BB_Checkout/js/mixin/shipping-mixin': true
        }
    }
},
'map': {
    '*': {
        'Wezz_Postcode/js/view/postcode': 'BB_Checkout/js/view/postcode-overwrite',
        'Magento_Ui/templates/form/element/input': 'BB_Checkout/templates/form/element/input-overwrite'
    }
}
 };
```

I also already tried clearing my M2 cache en browser cache.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't understand. It doesn't work for me. I tried this: var config = { map: { "*": { 'ui/template/form/element/select.html':'Bestworlds/ScoutBags/web/templates/select.html' } } };
please, Can you help me?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/155355)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah apparently **Magento_Ui/templates** is mapped to **ui/template** in:

> Magento\vendor\magento\module-ui\view\base\requirejs-config.js

So after adding **ui/template** it works.

Answer (score 1):

**The actual answer is in your base/requirejs-config.js**

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            //'Magento_Ui/templates/form/element/uploader/preview.html': 
            'ui/template/form/element/uploader/preview.html': 
                'Vendor_Module/template/form/element/uploader/preview.html'
        }
    }
};
```

Instead of using `Magento_Ui/templates` use `ui/template`

**NOTE:** Make sure if you want to override `adminhtml` template place your `requirejs-config.js` file inside `adminhtml`.
And if you want to override `base` template `requirejs-config.js` place inside `base`

Answer (score 0):

I've overridden by this way but it's not working...

Answer (score 0):

After transfering files from vendor/module_ui folder to custom theme folder (app/design). And editing this requirejs-config.js file, it finally worked!